# Protecting Wordpress Multisite from rogue programs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a seasoned java programmer but I'm new to php and wordpress. If I have 100 sites on a wordpress multisite installation and I give admin access to multiple developers, how can I protect the system from choking if one of them writes an infinite for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you structure the development of the sites. When using a networked site and developing/testing different coding ideas I've got, I usually spin off a new development area (my-wp-network-fakewebsite.com/test-area) and then create a brand new theme and try out all my development ideas there. That way, if I break something, it is a separate theme that is not active on the rest of the network.

I think thats what you are worried about, correct?